# Filling array with check boxes and sending it to php through http post

Tags: php, angular, typescript

So I am new to `Angular2` and I can't figure this out. I declared an `array` and fill it up by checking checkbox.  I want to send that `array` to `PHP` and use it to fill up a table.

This is my code for filling up the `array`.

```
selectedValue:Array<{name:string}>=[];

change(e, type) {
  console.log(e.target.checked);
  console.log(type.users); // users is of type User class that has attribute name

  if(e.target.checked) {
    this.selectedValue.push(type.name);
  } else {
   let updateItem = this.selectedValue.find(this.findIndexToUpdate, type.name);
   let index = this.selectedValue.indexOf(updateItem);
   this.selectedValue.splice(index, 1);
  }
}

findIndexToUpdate(type) { 
      return type.name === this;
}
```

`array` has a list of names that I check off and now i send it to a method:

```
 addioassign(){
      this.userService
          .insioassign(this.selectedValue)
          .subscribe();
      }
 }
```

and in my service class:

```
insioassign(info){
  return this._http.post("http://localhost/try/api/fill.php", info)
    .pipe(map(() => ""));
}
```

my php rest api:

```
<?php

$data1 = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

include "db.php";

//$report_id = $data1->report_id;    
$report_id = '8';

$sql="SELECT Eid FROM employee WHERE name IN ('$data1->name')";
if ($data1->name) {
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
}

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    $data = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         $data[] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
}

$r = count($data);    
for($x = 0; $x < $r; $x++) { 
    $s = implode('', $data[$x]);
    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO ioassign (report_id, Eid) VALUES($report_id, $s)";
    $result1 = $conn->query($sql1);
}
$conn->close();
```

PLEASE HELP. I've been on this since the past week and a half. and have found no conclusive answer. I've tried everything I could.

Comment: What is the issue, array is not getting filled with checked values?

Comment: No. Its getting filled. The issue is its not being recieved at php.